# How can I understand of multiple shift in C++?

Tags: c++

I need to read some txt file that of format like below:

```
key,value
key,value
...
```

I found a simple example code reading file.

```
ifstream input(argv[3]);

int key, value;
char c;
while (input >> key >> c >> value) {
    bptree.insert(key, value);
}
break;
```

But I'm through some trouble about understanding this code.

How did it work?
I can't imagine how this code work, especially this part:

```
while (input >> key >> c >> value)
```

Comment: "_I can't imagine how this code work, especially this part:_" Why do you find such code working, so hard to imagine? I see nothing wrong with it. It works, due to chained [`std::ifstream::operator>>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt) calls, in conjunction, with `std::ifstream` having conversion operator to bool: [`std::ifstream::operator bool`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool) defined.

Comment: It's equivalent to `while (input >> key, input >> c, input >> value)`.

Comment: you should have seen already `std::cout << "Hello world";` it is the same as `std::cout << "Hello " << "world";`

Comment: Maybe, it helps to know that (in your sample) the `operator >>` is an overloaded operator that hasn't much to do with the semantic of the original built-in `operator >>` for integral types which shifts bits to right.

Comment: OMG, I didn't know that... I only think ```>>``` is bit shift operator...:(. thx, I got it!